# JQuery UIDatePicker is not showing next previous buttons for chaning month

Tags: jquery, uidatepicker

I have one input field i.e. selected_date and following code is written to handle it:

$('#selected_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M d, yy' });
    $('#selected_date').click(
    function()
    {
        $('#selected_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'M d, yy' });
    });

I do not see next/previous button in the datepicker. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the jquery.ui.theme.css file and png icon files that are in the jquery.ui download?

Answer (score 0):

Under Jquery UI CSS, u will have to change afew codings.
Under /* states and images */, change the URL to the folder where u put the images in, example:url(../images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);